# poisson equation sobolev regularity - explicit computation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

Consider the Dirichlet problem on the circular strip $\Omega = \mathbb{T} \times (0,1)$:

$$\Delta u(x,y) = f(x,y) \ \text{  with } \  u(x,0) = u(x,1) = 0$$

It is a known result that for $f \in H^{s-2}$ we should have $u\in H^s$. I have a problem showing this explicitly. My attempt is as follows:

Writing $u(x,y) = \sum_k u_k(y)e^{ikx}$ and $f$ as fourier series in $x$ converts problem to a series of ODES on interval $(0,1)$:

$$u_k''(y) - k^2u_k(y) = f_k(y)$$
with homogeneous boundary conditions.
The solutions in terms of Green's function is
$$u_k(y) = \int_0^1 G_k(y,t) f_k(t) dt$$
where
$$G_k(y,t) = \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{\sinh[k(t-1)]\sinh(ky)}{k\sinh(k)} , \quad y \leq t\\
\dfrac{\sinh(kt)\sinh(k(y-1))}{k\sinh(k)} , \quad y \geq t \\
\end{cases}$$

Now we want to show $u \in H^s$,  in fact show
$$ \|u\|_s^2 = \sum_{p+q \leq s} \sum_k (1+k^2)^p \int_0^1 |u_k^{(q)}(y)|^2 dy \leq c\|f\|_{s-2}^2$$
Let's investigate the case when $p=s$ and $q=0$, it is enough to show my problem. In order for the above to work, we expect that
$$\|u_k\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 \approx k^{-4} \|f_k\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2$$
so that
$$(1+k^2)^s\|u_k\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 \approx (1+k^2)^{s-2}\|f_k\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2 $$

My problem is instead of the desired $k^{-4}$ I get only $k^{-3}$:

Note by Cauchy- Schwarz
$$\int_0^1 |u_k(y)|^2 dy = \int_0^1 |\int_0^1 G_k(y,t)f_k(t) dt \ |^2 dy \leq \|f_k\|_{L^2}^2 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |G_k(y,t)|^2 dy dt$$ 
and
$$\int_0^1 |G_k(y,t)|^2 dy dt = $$
$$ = \frac{1}{k^2\ \sinh^2(k)} \int_0^1 ( \sinh^2[k(t-1)] \int_0^t \sinh^2(ky) dy + \sinh^2(kt) \int_t^1 \sinh^2[k(y-1)] dy ) dt$$
$$= \frac{1}{4k^3\ \sinh^2(k)} \int_0^1 \sinh^2[k(t-1)] \{\sinh(2kt)-2kt\} + \sinh^2(kt)\{-\sinh[2k(t-1)] + 2k(t-1)\} dt$$
$$ = \frac{1}{4k^3\ \sinh^2(k)} (k + \frac{1}{k} - \frac{\cosh(2k)}{k} + \sinh(k)\cosh(k) ) $$
$$ \approx \frac{1}{k^3}$$

I've checked this computation many times and always get this $k^{-3}$. I wonder what can be going wrong? Perhaps there is some better way to bound it than with Cauchy-Schwartz right at the beginning of the computation?

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, what I'm about to write doesn't resolve the issues with your computation, but it does allow you to prove the $L^2$ estimate in a different way.

Starting from $u_k'' -k^2 u_k = f_k$ we multiply by $\bar{u}_k$ and integrate by parts:
$$
\int_0^1 |u_k'|^2 + k^2 |u_k|^2 = -\int_0^1 f_k \bar{u}_k.
$$
Since $u_k(0) = u_k(1) =0$ we can use Poincare on $(0,1)$ to bound
$$
\int_0^1 |u_k|^2 \le \int_0^1 |u_k'|^2.
$$
Plugging in and using Cauchy-Schwarz then shows that
$$
(1+k^2) \int_0^1 |u_k|^2 \le \left( \int_0^1 |f_k|^2\right)^{1/2} \left( \int_0^1 |u_k|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$
and hence
$$
(1+k^2)^s \int_0^1 |u_k|^2 \le (1+k^2)^{s-2}\int_0^1 |f_k|^2.
$$

Also, with a bit of work you can extend this method to get control of $u_k^{(q)}$ as well.

Comment: Very clever.

What bothers me is my calculation should work. If we consider the Green's function as an operator $G_k: f_k(y) \rightarrow \int_0^1 G_k(y,t) f_k(t) dt$ then it is a Hilbert Schmidt integral operator from $L^2(0,1)$ to $L^2(0,1)$ with norm $|||G_k||| = \|G_k\|_{L^2((0,1)\times(0,1))}$ and so I should in fact get the right estimate above.

Anyways thanks for the very clever approach.