# Poisson equation infinite strip Sobolev regularity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, poissons-equation

Consider the equation (with $l_-=0, l_+=l>0)$
\begin{align}
 \left\{\begin{array}{rclclcl}
  -\Delta u (s,t) & = & f(s,t) &&&& \text{for } (s,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times (0,l), \\[6pt]
  u(s,l_\pm)  & = & g_\pm(s) &&&& \text{for } s\in \mathbb{R}, 
 \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
My aim is to show that $u\in H^{2}(\mathbb{R}\times (0,l))$ if $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}\times (0,l))$ and $g_\pm \in H^{\frac 32}(\mathbb{R})$. I follow the ideas in the book "Elliptic problems in domains with piecewise smooth boundaries" by Nazarov and Plamenevsky (Chapter 2.2.2). By density it is sufficient to assume that both $f$ and $g_\pm$ are in $C_c^\infty$ and looking for solutions that are in $C^2$ and continuous up to the boundary. Applying a Fourier transform in $s-$ direction yields the problem
\begin{align}\label{eq:DBVP_FT}
 \left\{\begin{array}{rclclcl}
  -(\partial_t^2 - \lambda^2) \widehat{u} (\lambda,t) & = & \widehat{f}(\lambda,t) &&&& \text{for } t\in (0,l), \\[6pt]
  \widehat{u}(\lambda,l_\pm)  & = & \widehat{g_\pm}(\lambda) &&&& \text{for } t\in \mathbb{R}. 
 \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
Now the claim is that
\begin{align}
||\widehat{u}(\lambda,\cdot)||_{L^2(0,l)}\lesssim \lambda^{-4}||\widehat{f}(\lambda,\cdot)||_{L^2(0,l)}+ \sum_{\pm} \lambda^{-1} |\widehat{g_\pm}(\lambda)|^2.
\end{align}
This can be achieved by writing $\widehat{u}(\lambda,\cdot)$ in terms of a Green's function $\Gamma$:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:GF}
  \widehat{u}(\lambda,t)= \int_0^l \Gamma(\lambda, t,\tau)\widehat{f}(\lambda,\tau)d \tau + \frac{\sinh \lambda t}{\sinh \lambda l} \widehat{g_+}(\lambda) - \frac{\sinh \lambda (t-l)}{\sinh \lambda l} \widehat{g_-}(\lambda)
 \end{equation}
with
\begin{align}
  \Gamma(t,\tau) = \frac{1}{2\lambda\sinh\lambda l}\left(\cosh \lambda (t + \tau -l) - \cosh \lambda (l-|t-\tau|)\right).
 \end{align}

**Question 1:** The estimate for the boundary values works well but for the estimate involving $\Gamma$ I'm failing. Using Cauchy-Schwarz it suffices to bound $||\Gamma||_{L^2((0,l)^2)}^2$, but when I calculate the integral explicitly (using Mathematica), I can only bound it by $\lambda^{-3}||\widehat{f}(\lambda,\cdot)||_{L^2(0,l)}$. Do you have any ideas how to resolve this problem?

**Question 2:** I'm not sure why this is sufficient to finally bound the $H^{s+2}$-norm of $u$ as by Plancherel one would need to control terms like $(1+|\lambda|^2+|\lambda|^4)||\widehat{u}(\lambda,\cdot)||_{L^2(0,l)}$.

**Question 3:** Moreover, I'm interested in a way how to estimate $||\partial_t\widehat{u}(\lambda,\cdot)||_{L^2(0,l)}$ as partial integration would yield again boundary terms (involving the value of $\partial_t\widehat{u}(\lambda,l_\pm)$) which is unkown.

**Question 4:** According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2138020) it is quite reasonable to expect the $\lambda^{-4}$ estimate. As the Green function I gave you above should be correct, is there any other possibility to derive the desired estimate using other inequalities than Cauchy-Schwarz?

Thank you very much in adavance!

Note: I'm aware that there were posted several questions like this here but unfortunately, I haven't found an answer where the inhomogeneous boundary conditions are treated as then arguments involving the standard Poincaré inequality are not available...

Comment: I assume you are taking $g_{\pm}\in H^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})$. But what are you assuming about $u$. A weak solution in which space? $H^1$?

Comment: I edited my post above to clarify the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting a different approach, so this might not be the answer you want.

Let $U=\mathbb{R}\times(0,l)$. By standard trace theory you can find a
function $G\in H^{2}(U)$ such that $G(s,l_{\pm})=g_{\pm}(s)$ and $\Vert
G\Vert_{H^{2}(U)}\leq C(\Vert g_{-}\Vert_{H^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})}+\Vert
g_{+}\Vert_{H^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})})$.

If you define $v=u-G$, you find that
$-\Delta v=f+G=:F$ and $v(s,l_{\pm})=0$. So now you are in $H_{0}^{1}(U)$ and
Poincare's inequality $\Vert w\Vert_{L^{2}(U)}\leq C\Vert\nabla
w\Vert_{L^{2}(U)}$ holds for all $w\in H_{0}^{1}(U)$. Hence, you can take
$\Vert\nabla w\Vert_{L^{2}(U)}$ as an equivalent norm in $H_{0}^{1}(U)$.
In
turn, you can apply Lax Milgram theorem to find a weak solution $v\in
H_{0}^{1}(U)$ of $-\Delta v=F$ with $\Vert\nabla v\Vert_{L^{2}(U)}\leq C\Vert
F\Vert_{L^{2}(U)}$.

Now, there is a trick to reduce the problem to the entire space. Le
$\varphi\in C^{\infty}([0,l])$ be such that $\varphi=1$ in $[0,l/3]$ and
$\varphi=0$ in $[2/3l,l]$. Then $v=\varphi v+(1-\varphi)v=:v_{1}+v_{2}$.

Since $v_{1}=0$ in $\mathbb{R}\times\lbrack2/3l,l]$, you can extend it to be
zero for $t\geq l$. Thus $v_{1}$ satifies $-\Delta v_{1}=F_{1}$ in
$\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)$, where $F_{1}=-2\nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla
v+\varphi F-v\Delta\varphi\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty))$. By
reflecting $v_{1}$ that is $v_{1}(s,t):=-v_{1}(s,-t)$ for $t<0$, you get a
solution $v_{1}\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ of $-\Delta v_{1}=F_{1}$ in
$\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Hence, you can use Fourier transforms to show that
$\Vert\nabla^{2}v_{1}\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}\leq C\Vert F_{1}%
\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}$.

For $v_{2}$ you get something similar. Since $v_{2}=0$ in $\mathbb{R}%
\times\lbrack0,l/3]$, you can extend it to be zero for $t<0$. Thus $v_{2}$
satifies $-\Delta v_{2}=F_{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,l)$ and you can
proceed in a similar way.

Finally, observe that
\begin{align*}
\Vert\nabla^{2}v\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}  & =\Vert\nabla^{2}v_{1}%
+\nabla^{2}v_{2}\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}\leq C\Vert F_{1}\Vert
_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}+C\Vert F_{2}\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}\\
& \leq C\Vert F\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}+C\Vert v\Vert_{H_{0}%
^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}\leq C\Vert F\Vert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})}\\
& \leq C(\Vert f\Vert_{L^{2}(U)}+\Vert g_{-}\Vert_{H^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})}+\Vert
g_{+}\Vert_{H^{3/2}(\mathbb{R})})
\end{align*}

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for this approach. Unfortunately, my reputation is to low to cast feedback directly. I wonder if there is a direct way to adapt your proof for the Neumann problem or more general boundary conditions. For example, the Green's function of the Neumann problem is the same as above (with two + signs before the cosh's) and therefore the prove should proceed similarly. Is this also true for your approach?

Comment: You can use trace theory to make the normal derivative zero. The problem with Neumann is that Poincare's inequality no longer works. If you can prove the existence of a weak solution, then to prove regularity, you can use an even reflection instead of an odd reflection.